# (I'm) Sorry about your dad

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

Let's say my friend had just lost his dad and I wanted to express my sympathy, would I need to include "I'm" or is it okay without?

(I'm) sorry about your dad?

My concern is if it would sound like I was apologizing for something about the dad if I didn't include "I'm".

Answer (score 2):

If your condolences are heartfelt, nobody will be picky about grammar.

However, I feel you should say "I'm sorry about ...".  I can see no benefit in leaving out the subject and verb of this sentence. There is no need for you to be casual or save words.